# SQL Transactions across multiple databases

Tags: sql, transactions

so I am looking to set an upload service to move data from sql express to a full version. Due to the lack of agent on express I am writing the service myself in c#, I plan on using transactions to ensure data integrity.

Can i have a single transaction cover 2 databases...

meaning...

I want to read from express, insert into 2012 then update express showing "uploaded" status, since these are two separate databases, what is the best way to ensure data integrity between both sql instances.

if any of the 3 operations fail the entire transaction should be rolled back and tried again at a later time...

Comment: Any specific dbms you are using?

Comment: @jarlh Not sure if they have specifics in mind, I plan on running SQL 2012 servers and SQL2012 express on the low end , otherwise everything would be in code c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Distributed Transactions. See this article on TechNet. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213077(v=sql.80).aspx,